# Permission denied when using -exec {} ls with find command

Tags: find, ls

When run following command it gives me `permission denied` message for all the files.

```
find /data/code/ -name "*.jar" -exec {} ls \;


find: `/data/code/project/shared/build/thirdparty/log4j-1.2.8/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar': Permission denied
```

But if I do

```
ls  /data/code/project/shared/build/thirdparty/log4j-1.2.8/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
```

It prints gives the proper output without any `permission denied` message.

```
/data/code/project/shared/build/thirdparty/log4j-1.2.8/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
```

What am I doing wrong?

p.s. : I need to list and remove all the jar files in `/data/code`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While doing:

```
find /data/code/ -name "*.jar" -exec {} ls \;
```

you are trying the execute the file found (e.g. `/data/code/project/shared/build/thirdparty/log4j-1.2.8/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar`) with `ls` as an argument to it, leading to the permission denied error.

Just switch the order:

```
find /data/code/ -name "*.jar" -exec ls {} \;
```

GNU `find` has `-ls` option too, so in GNU `find`, you can just do:

```
find /data/code/ -name "*.jar" -ls
```

Comment: Or use `find /data/code -name '*.jar' -ls`

Comment: OMG. I am horrible at even copying and pasting commands : (

Thanks a lot